# JPA oracle substring

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

how to write a named query for Oracle using Hibernate
    SELECT * FROM Table where substring(Car, 2, 1) = '1'
oracle has substr intead of substring
and i know that JPA has substring as well, is it the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the procedure as:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SUB_STRING(STR IN VARCHAR2, STR_DELIMITOR IN VARCHAR2:='.',STR_PART IN VARCHAR2:='1')RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
STR_RET VARCHAR2(4000):=NULL;
BEGIN
    IF STR_PART = '1' THEN

        STR_RET := substr(STR, 1, instr(STR,STR_DELIMITOR,1,1)-1);

    ELSE

        STR_RET := substr(STR, instr(STR,STR_DELIMITOR,1,STR_PART-1)+1,instr(STR, STR_DELIMITOR, 1,STR_PART)- instr(STR, STR_DELIMITOR, 1,STR_PART-1)-1);

    END IF;

RETURN STR_RET;
END;`

Then you can use it like this:

`SELECT GET_SUB_STRING(COLUMN_NAME,',','1') FROM YOUR_TABLE`